# unable to transfer big files using C# NetworkStream

Tags: c#, networking

I'm trying to transfer a database using the C# class NetworkStream, but every time a different amount of bytes is transformed.
even though the database is minimal (388KB), only a part of it passes to the client.
a small text file is passed without problems.

server:

```
 NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
 byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +   "\\viruses_database.accdb");
 netStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
```

client:

```
NetworkStream netStream=client.GetStream();
Stream stream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\viruses_database.accdb", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

 int length=bytes.Length;
 int cnt = 0;

 while (netStream.CanRead && length==bytes.Length)
 {
     length = netStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
     cnt++;
 }
 stream.Close();
```

I suspect that the problem lies in the fact that the transfering isn't done asynchronously

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

That's a bug.  You only received *length* bytes but you are writing 1024 bytes.  This will arbitrarily corrupt the data in the file and make its final size unpredictable.  Fix:

```
  stream.Write(bytes, 0, length);
```

Do favor the CopyTo() method (available since .NET 4) to avoid bugs like this:

```
  using (var input = client.GetStream())
  using (var output = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
      input.CopyTo(output);
  }
```

Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() is another bug, it is too unpredictable and you rarely can write to it when your program is installed on the user's machine.  Data files belong in the appdata directory, use Environment.GetFolderPath()